# NetSuite custom customer center - Saved saved - show all customers of a category

Tags: netsuite

I am building a customer center ssp application and i need to create a saved search to show all customers of a particular category.

For this I need Lists -> Customers permission to this customer center role, but apparently we cannot do it.

- What is a relevant ss file code for this saved search? or
- Is there another way to do it?

Comment: The customer center has some inherent restrictions to protect data, the list of customers is one of those restrictions.  You -might- be able to use a script set to run as admin on a custom tab within the customer center to pull saved search results & either export immediately as CSV or display on screen - note the on screen results are limited to 1000 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function export(){
    var results = nlapiSearchRecord('customer', 2830); //rec type, search id
    var header = new Array();
    var row = new Array();
    header[0] = 'name'; // search column headers, # is the numeric order of the column, text is the text displayed as header in the export
    header[3] = 'class';
    var data = header + '\n';
        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
            var result = results[i];
            var columns = result.getAllColumns();
            row[0] = result.getValue(columns[0]); // retrieving search result line data for column 0 in search
            row[3] = result.getText(columns[3]); // column 3's line data
        data += row + '\n';
    }
    var file = nlapiCreateFile('customerdata.csv', 'CSV', data); //csv detail
    response.setContentType(file.getType(), 'customerdata.csv'); //exports csv for user
    response.write(file.getValue());  
}
```